# Getting 'externally-managed-environment' error when trying to install with pip, DESPITE being in a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, package, python-venv

First thing's first: my OS is openSUSE Tumbleweed, my Python version is 3.11.7, and my pip version is 23.2.2

My goal is as follows: I want to use pip to install the pytictoc package into a virtual environment I create with Python.

My understanding of how to do this is:

1. Run `python3 -m venv env` to create a directory called `env` for my virtual environment.
2. Then, within that directory, I run `source bin/activate` to activate the virtual environment
3. Ensure that the virtual environment is indeed running; `(env)` should appear at the start of the current line, and any subsequent lines.
4. Run `python -m pip install pytictoc` to install the pytictoc package to the virtual environment

When trying to execute these steps, 1-3 go without any problems, however running the command in step 4 yields the `externally-managed-environment` error. Here is the full error message:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try
    zypper install python311-xyz, where xyz is the package
    you are trying to install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-rpm packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3.11 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.
    
    If you wish to install a non-rpm packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use `pipx install xyz`, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Install pipx via `zypper install python311-pipx` .
```

As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything right, so I'm lost as to how to approach this. I've seen solutions involving tacking on `--break-system-packages` to pip, but this seems to be for cases where the user is NOT using a virtual environment. As far as I can tell, there are no other forums where someone has my exact problem, except [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1465218/pip-error-on-ubuntu-externally-managed-environment-%C3%97-this-environment-is-extern) askubuntu question. The user responded to the top answer, explaining that they still receive the error message despite being in a virtual environment. However, this comment didn't receive any response.

There may be other solutions, such as using pipx, or other virtual environments like conda. Unfortunately, for me it is *essential* that I make the virtual environment with venv, and that I use pip to install the package "pytictoc" specifically. I cannot install the package system-wide.

I appreciate any help or response anyone is able to offer. Thank you for taking the time to read this!

Comment: `type -a python` — is it the Python from the `env/bin` ?

Comment: hm, I get the following: ```python is aliased to `/usr/bin/python3.11'
python is /~/env/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
python is /bin/python
```
I should have mentioned that I have python3 aliased to python on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `python` **aliased** (in your shell) **to** `/usr/bin/python3.11`. So when you run `python -m pip` in command line you actually run global `pip`, not the `pip` from the venv, and the global `pip` complains about "externally managed environment".

When you activate a virtual environment you should unalias `python`; you can insert `unalias python python3` into `activate` script. Or always run `venv/bin/python -m pip` with absolute or relative path.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. However, I'm not sure where I should put `unalias python python3` inside of the `activate` script. Would it be fine to just put it at the very top?

Comment: @VenutianVermin Doesn't matter. At any place. The very top is ok.